# Ubuntu: how to start an app on a different desktop

Tags: ubuntu

Automatically starting application show up on the 1st desktop. Is there a way to make them appear on a different (2nd, 3rd, etc) desktop?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using compiz (desktop effects), yes.

Just install the CompizConfigurationManager, it has a plugin which allows to set such rules. I don't know what it is called exactly, but you'll sure recognize it if you see it (something with Window Location or Place Windows).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific application to end up on a specific workspace, you can use [Devilspie](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie) :)